# Setting up a tube rig for an astronaut character

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

I have a scene with an astronaut character with tubes on the side of the helmet going to the back. I would like to set up a rig to allow the helmet to turn and the tubes react like they would in real life.

I have spent an entire week trying to figure out a method. I have tried soft body and cloth techniques that work for a tentacle or hair but I am unable to get the ends to work properly. I thought I had it going but the sim blows up and the tube goes all over the place.

Below is a screenshot of my scene with the main character head and armature hidden. The tube sticking out strait is the one I am trying to get to bend around to the back like the one that is draped across the shoulder going around to the back.

[image]

Comment: I use the Laplacian Deform Modifier for those jobs.  I can put up an answer with detailed method if required.

Comment: The Laplacian is a decent tool but its not recommended for animation. I am going to be animating this character. I need a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: So how did you get on with this?  I was puzzled by your comment re: Laplacian Modifier being 'not recommended for animation', as I'm doing this frequently and without issues.

I also knocked up a similar scenario to yours and 'floated the character through 360 degrees, using Laplacian on all tubes.  There were no issues with the animation being present, only with the modifier's usual deform limitations.  i.e the loose tube wants to twist and kink when it's taken back too far.

Comment: Continued... A bevelled curve for that tube is a breeze to curl back but as you're using a meshed tube, I went back to that and got it to work ok by controlling it's rope-like movements with a straight line curve's control points.